# Android Studio emulator not working correctly (zooming in and is pink)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I updated Android Studio and now I got some problems. My emulator is pink and is zooming in automatically.
[image]

Comment: You should need use [Genymotion emulator ] (https://www.genymotion.com) for better development experience.

Comment: To which version you updated?

Comment: Android Studio 2.2.2. Newest version, with blueprint and that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pink and zooming in effect You experienced is a result of **Skin**. You can change the skin inside **Android Virtual Device Manager**, under **Edit** of Your emulator.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the frame in the Android Virtual Device Mangar editor.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to,

Tools\Android\AVD Manager\

In AVD Manager window, edit the desired emulator, then as below shot illustrates choose "No Skin".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Android Default Emulator is very slow.

Try **[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)** with android studio plugin.

It is faster than default and easy to use. You just have to create a free Individual account.

Also to increase speed of default emulator increase the heap size

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!

Comment: Is there a free version?

Comment: yes, you have to sign up for free to use in Personal Development

Comment: Oh, I fixed my problem now, but maybe I will download it later.